# Strange crash on row deletion from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array:

```
var users = [Users]()
```

And in `editActionsForRowAt` I do following:

```
self.viewModel.users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.usersTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

and it crashes on `deleteRows` with the next error:

```
attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only 
contains 0 rows before the update
```

I tried to debug and found the next: when I remove a user from the `array`:

```
self.viewModel.users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

it removes somehow the row also! Like before this line

```
self.usersTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
```

gives me `1`. After deletion from the array BUT before `deleteRows` it becomes `equal to`0`. I cannot understand the problem. It's so weird. Can someone help me to understand it?

**UPDATE**

`numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.viewModel.users.count
}
```

Comment: Show your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods.

Comment: You need to wrap your changes in `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` — https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates

Comment: @rmaddy I've just updated my question

Comment: @matt is it a good solution for deletion only 1 object, using `batches`?

Comment: after you remove a user from viewModel's array, can you check if tableview delegate methods are getting called? If so can you check if you are doing KVO on the users array?